# How is `exports` used to initialize Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
  // Save a reference to the global object (`window` in the browser, `exports`
  // on the server).
  var root = this;
```

What is exports?  I can understand setting root.Backbone to an object literal as now one can add properties to it.

However, the comment in the source above implies that `this` points to window in browsers and exports on the server?

Is this true?

The reason I ask is because this code here:

```
  var Backbone;
  if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    Backbone = exports;
  } else {
    Backbone = root.Backbone = {};
  }
```

Why would you define all the modules outside of the namespace (to exports), defeating the purpose of of the closure the library is contained it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exports` is the name of the exported object in the [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/) module format, primarily used by [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

In CommonJS every javascript source file is a module, and whatever you assign to `exports` will be the "return value" of that file. So the line in Backbone source code:

```
Backbone = exports;
```

Says: "define Backbone as the export object of this module." Later on, when they attach properties such as `Backbone.Model` to the `Backbone` root object, they are attached to the export value.

Comment: If CommonJS exports the exports variable.  Then how does backbone get away with defining all it's modules on top of it..i.e. Backbone.Events, Backbone.View,  etc.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist, `exports` is the export object of the module. In CommonJS one file is one module, so each file gets its own `exports` object.

Comment: if you have, `window.global_1`, `window.global_1` is available in a singular global space.  It does not have a different reference in each 'file'.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist, node.js doesn't really have a global root object like `window`. It has some global objects (http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html), but the code you write operates in module scope by default. Javascript on the server is somewhat different from the browser, yes.